# Chrome-extension in production looks different than in development. WHY?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im creating an Angular2 Chrome-extension App.

It looks great when I created it in production.

[image]

However, this is how it looks when I upload it as a chrome-extension in development mode (Look at the logo and buttons).

[image]

The logo SHOULD be 75px (which it is in development), however in production it decides to be 87px even if the chrome tools tell me its 75px...

The same happens with the buttons.

Am I doing something wrong?

I did add the

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

tag.

It seems like chrome is taking over control of the viewport?

Comment: Maybe check out your 'zoom' setting in Chrome. (CTRL+MOUSESCROLL)

Comment: @FerryKranenburg Thanks for the hint! It was actually at 110%. And also my font size were measured in em's and not px and somehow chrome doesnt like it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your 'zoom' setting in Chrome. (CTRL+MOUSESCROLL)

Answer (score 1):

Check out zoom settings on chrome and also make sure your font size is displayed in px and not em's since somehow chrome extensions do not replicate em size as they are in development.